# How to know what IPs are associated with an authorised server?

Tags: ip, web-service

My goal is to analyze the traffic of an Android application, to check if it contacts any IPs not associated with the server it is meant to contact.

Using PCAPRemote I created a connection log file and transferred it to the PC, where I am analyzing it with WireShark.

My problem is that there are dozens of different IPs, and I can't find any information about these IPs on the internet.

What do you recommend to understand which IPs are associated with the service?

P.S. All these IPs in the pcap are of the application only, not of the whole system

Comment: OP, it sounds like you are saying that the application should connect to IP addresses of servers that are run by the company that created the application.  If that's the case, then any IP address that the app connects to should have a PTR record that reverses to a FQDN within this company's domain.  This FQDN should also then forward to the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use `whois <ip>` (or any online IP info tool) to find out information about each IP

Alternatively, you can find or create a blacklist of IPs and just check if your application is sending data or otherwise contacting <sup>1</sup> undesirable parties. Realistically the range of possibilities for that is quite large, so the contents of the blacklist will depend on your risk model and/or goal (you could use a [list of advertisers](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Filter-lists-from-around-the-web), for example).

You can also whitelist the "allowable" IPs, however that would require working knowledge of the necessary requests of the application.

<sup>1</sup><sub>data is sometimes sent through non-traditional protocols [such as DNS](https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2020/dns-tunneling-definition-and-protection/) to avoid detection</sub>

Comment: the mod I am talking about is a mod of a music streaming application. As I wrote above it uses a lot of different IP addresses, and I don't find much information on whois. Perhaps the only way to understand which IPs are good is to first check those of the original application and then compare them with the modified one

Comment: @Momoa Seems reasonable, given that the same servers are being queried (and it's not picking from a large pool or is p2p, in which case there would be too much discrepancy